# Store file reference in LDAP

Tags: file, ldap, jndi

In initial phase, developer started with storing small file in an LDAP attribute. Later, as file size grow, it became a problem. Now I am planning to change it like, storing file content in disk and file path in a attribute. My doubt, Is it possible for the OpenLDAP server to automatically serve the file content, as the client read that attribute??

I saw reference attributes like LabeledURI. Is there any specific Attribute to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not possible and a bad idea.

A LDAP directory should never be treated as a file store, as it is designed to host many but small objects. To be performant, requests should be as short as possible.

A NAS would be better suited to host those files.

You'll have to modify your code to access those files based on a filename stored in the directory.

Comment: Thanks. What about putting a OpenLDAP Server in the front (as a proxy) and if the Query is for that  attribute, then make the proxy to get the content from file server and serve to the client? (I have no experience with LDAP proxy).

Comment: Out of the box, you can't. You could write an OpenLDAP plugin to achieve this, but this still won't be a good idea, as you'll generate a lot of I/O and block threads on the LDAP server during the time you're serving the file. I doubt that the performance will be stellar...

Comment: Thanks. So let me try some other round-about ways like fakeLDAP server, etc

Answer (score 1):

Certainly storing the URI to a file (or any other Resource) is possible and often done.

Serving a file, depends on the LDAP server implementation and size of the file. Certificates and photos are often stored in LDAP.

eDirectory, as an example, streams data over a certain size, to a file in the DIB store. However, the LDAP protocol is not very efficient in streaming large blocks or data.

-jim